# Solving $\log_2 x\log_3 2x + \log_3 x\log_2 4x > 0$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I have following inequality:

$$\log_2 x\log_3 2x + \log_3 x\log_2 4x > 0$$

which I have reduced to:

$$\frac{\log x}{\log 2}\frac{2x}{\log 3} + \frac{\log x}{\log 3}\frac{4x}{\log 2} > 0$$

$$6x \log x > 0$$

For this to be defined, $x > 0$; also, if $x > 1$, then both $6x$ and $\log x$ are positive.

But I do not know how to solve it completely.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $$\frac{\log x}{\log 2}\frac{\log 2x}{\log 3} + \frac{\log x}{\log 3}\frac{\log 4x}{\log 2} > 0?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be: $$\frac{\log_2 x \log_2 2x}{\log_2 3} + \frac{\log_2 x \log_2 4x}{\log_2 3} > 0$$
$$\log_2 x (1+\log_2 x) + \log_2 x (2+\log_2 x) > 0$$
$$\log_2 x \cdot (3+2\log_2 x) > 0$$
now you have to consider two cases: \begin{cases}
\log_2 x >0 \\
3+2\log_2 x >0
\end{cases} and
\begin{cases}
\log_2 x <0 \\
3+2\log_2 x <0
\end{cases}

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes I got it myself.

Comment: @Sil: since $\log_2 3>0$ we can multiply both sides by it and get rid of it

Comment: @Sil: Oh, yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Be carefull, your idea should be translated to

$$\frac{\log x}{\log 2}\frac{\log 2x}{\log 3} + \frac{\log x}{\log 3}\frac{\log 4x}{\log 2} > 0$$

Next step would be

$$\frac{\log x}{\log 2}\frac{(\log x +\log 2)}{\log 3} + \frac{\log x}{\log 3}\frac{(\log x+\log 4)}{\log 2} > 0$$

remember that $\log 2>0$ and $\log 3 >0$. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes I got it myself.

Comment: @Shiv: If you are satisfied, please, choose one as an answer. Doing this you avoid your question popping up in the question list.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{cases}
\log_2x>0\\
3+2\log_2x>0
\end{cases}\quad\lor$
$\quad\begin{cases}
\log_2x<0\\
3+2\log_2x<0
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
x>1\\
\log_2x>-\dfrac32
\end{cases}\quad\lor$
$\quad\begin{cases}
0<x<1\\
\log_2x<-\dfrac32
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
x>1\\
x>2^{-\frac32}
\end{cases}\quad\lor$
$\quad\begin{cases}
0<x<1\\
0<x<2^{-\frac32}
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
x>1\\
x>\dfrac1{\sqrt8}
\end{cases}\quad\lor$
$\quad\begin{cases}
0<x<1\\
0<x<\dfrac1{\sqrt8}
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
x>1\\
x>\dfrac{\sqrt2}4
\end{cases}\quad\lor$
$\quad\begin{cases}
0<x<1\\
0<x<\dfrac{\sqrt2}4
\end{cases}$

$x>1\quad\lor\quad0<x<\dfrac{\sqrt2}4\;.$

Have you managed to finish now?

Comment: Yes, I have finished it.